# Как можно проверить существует ли функция в js

Tags: функции, javascript

Как можно проверить существует ли функция в js, вот пример из кода

```
    var text = 'template:template2'
    var rout = text.split(':');

    if(typeof rout[1] == 'function') {

        var data = eval( rout[1] + '();');  
        console.log(data);
    }
    else {console.log(rout[1]);}
```

это не работает, а значит вопрос, как можно `rout[1]` проверить является ли она функцией?? И чтобы в консоли не сыпалась ошибка!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если функция расположена в глобальном контексте, то можно воспользоваться тем, что функции это по сути обычные объекты внутри window.

```
name="checkThisName";
if ( isFunction(window[name]) ) alert ("I am function");

// isFunction взято со стэка
function isFunction(functionToCheck)  {
    var getType = {};
    return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

В локальном контексте проверить получится с помощью eval:

```
name= "funcName";
alert( eval("isFunction("+name+");") );
```

Comment: Спасибо, но выводил в консоль и не может определить - undefined

вот так создавал функцию - function hage_1(){return 'teeet';} и её не может определить

Comment: Вероятно Вы создали функцию не в глобальном контексте. Обновил ответ, добавив решение для локального контекста.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а можно последний вопрос, а если функции не существует в консоли в браузере всегда будет выскакивать : Uncaught ReferenceError: name_function is not defined

Comment: try ... catch ?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все просто супер))))))

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo(x) {
    return x;
}

if (typeof (foo) === "function") {
    // Проверка пройдена
    // Вызываем функцию...
}

if (typeof (bar) === "function") {
    // Проверка провалена, функция bar не объявлена    
}
```

Comment: Это я знаю, а как проверить если название функции хранится в переменной как в примере?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*** Моё простое и гениальное решение! ***/
// Где-то в коде объявлена функция, например подключено расширение.
const FOO = () => alert('Тестируем...');

// Динамическая проверка имени, например надо проверить некий список подключенных расширений.
let myFunctionName = 'FOO';

// Т. к. глобальные константы не становятся свойствами объекта window,
// в отличие от var-переменных, то проверить просто через:
// 'typeof window[myFunctionName]' - не получится. 
if (new Function('return typeof ' + myFunctionName)() !== 'undefined') FOO();
else console.error('Функция с именем ' + myFunctionName + ' не существует!')

// P.S. Ни каких try…catch и eval'ов!
```

Comment: new Function - это и есть одна из форм eval: Всё также выполняет код из строки.

Comment: Ну если прямо таки хочется с eval, то можно сделать и так:
if (eval('typeof ' + myFunctionName) !== 'undefined') FOO();