# Как вызвать функцию через её имя в виде строки?

Tags: javascript, функции

Пользователь вводит строку, из которой достается ключевое слово, для которой заранее подготовлена функция с похожим именем. Её как-то можно вызвать без `eval()` ?

```js
bubu("http://One.com/bubu.png");

function bubu(str) {
  let key = (str.match(/(One|Two|Three)/ig) || ["Other"])[0];

  window["handle" + "Test"](); // Работает для глобальной функции
  
  bubu["handle" + key](); // Error. Где же сохраняется функция?
                          // *Должен сработать handleOne()

  function   handleOne() { console.log( 'one' ); }
  function   handleTwo() { console.log( 'two' ); }
  function handleThree() { console.log('three'); }
  function handleOther() { console.log('other'); }
}


function handleTest() { console.log( 'Window-test' ); }
```

P.s. ну и код функций чуть сложнее и разнообразнее, что делает невозможным создать одну с параметрами)

Comment: почему бы не поместить функции в объект и вызывать как метод? На сколько мне известно то в джаваскрипте нет возможности вызывать так функции.

Comment: @Arendach Хороший вариант, но придется разместить большой объект с функциями вверху кода, чтобы они были доступны) А такой вариант вызова из примера показался красивее, если бы был возможен.

Comment: но зато функции будут красиво сгруппированы в объекте и не будут мешать никому :)  что тоже плюс

Comment: Он красивый и понятный, из-за того. что тут нет никакой реализации, реализовав там тонну кода для работы, будет ужасно не удобно. Чем действительно вынести это в модули. Не зря же их придумали, просто как-раз устали от такого быдло-кода.

Comment: Легко! Да и ещё с проверкой на существование:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167417/403461

Answer (score -1, accepted):

на классах, ES6

```js
class Bubu {
  constructor() {
    this.actions = {
      'handleOne': 'handleOne',
      'handleTwo': 'handleTwo',
      'handleThree': 'handleThree',
      'handleOther': 'handleOther'
    };

    this._init();
  }

  _init() {
    const key = 'Three';

    this[this.actions['handle' + key]]();
  }

  handleOne() {
    console.log('1');
  }

  handleTwo() {
    console.log('2');
  }

  handleThree() {
    console.log('3');
  }

  handleOther() {
    console.log('other');
  }
}

new Bubu();
```

Answer (score 2):

Локальные функции и переменные не являются свойствами какого либо объекта в юзеркоде... поэтому, динамическое обращение к ним (по имени в виде `string`) - невозможно без помещения в объект или использования `eval`.

---

То что ниже - ответ не точно на заданный вопрос, а на часть комментария относительно функций в объекте:

> ...но придется разместить большой объект с функциями вверху кода, чтобы они были доступны

На самом деле очень скорбно видеть подобные проблемы, представляя страдания от ручной сборки js-файлов и прочих ассетов. Ведь сейчас это легко автоматизируется:

1. Устанавливаем в систему *[node](https://nodejs.org)* (если этого не сделано ранее), и перейдя в папку проекта, инициализируем его через `$ npm init`
2. Ставим любой сборщик aka бандлер (*[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org)*/*[Rollup](https://rollupjs.org)*/*[Parcel](https://parceljs.org)*/...) и готовим проект по первой страничке его документации. Это минутное дело, но можно взять и полностью готовый бойлерплейт с github
3. Создаем файл *src/utils/helpers.js**, в котором объявляем и экспортируем вспомогательные функции:

```
function   one() { console.log( 'one' ); }
function   two() { console.log( 'two' ); }
function three() { console.log('three'); }
function other() { console.log('other'); }

export { one, two, three, other };
```

4. В *src/index.js* (или в любом из js-файлов с основной логикой) - импортируем** и используем:

```
import * as handlers from './utils/handlers.js';  // это создаст объект handlers, содержащий в своих свойствах все (*) именованные экспорты указанного файла 

bubu('http://One.com/bubu.png');

function bubu(str) {
  let key = (str.match(/One|Two|Three/i) || ['Other'])[0].toLowerCase();
  handlers[key](); 
}
```

5. Запускаем сборку (`$ npm run build`), или сервер разработки (`$ npm start` / `$ npm run dev`).

В целом, сборщик способен не только "сшивать" пару js-файлов в один. Являясь достаточно универсальным инструментом, он может взять на себя огромный объем и другой рутинной механической работы (обработку html- и css-файлов, изображений, вызов транспайлеров/минификаторов, и т.д.).
Плюс, популярные сборщики в режиме разработки предоставляют удобный LiveReload - без, кхм, релоада страницы :)

---

*<sup>* Все исходники принято держать в папке src/, а структура вложенных в нее, большого значения не имеет. Но имя папки "utils" узнаваемо, и не только людьми - например, VS Code отображает для нее соответствующую иконку (мелочь, и все же реально помогает быстрее ориентироваться в дереве папок проекта). 


** Импортировать можно и не все экспорты модуля - а только те, которые нужны. Например,

`import { one, three } from './utils/handlers.js';`

Это не только ради порядка, есть и практическая польза: бандлер умеющий tree shaking, сам найдет и отбросит мертвый (неиспользуемый) код. Таким образом, можно держать личные наработки в общих модулях, и частично использовать их в разных проектах - не опасаясь за объем итоговой сборки. Что самое приятное, многие современные библиотеки тоже поддерживают подобный импорт.</sup>*

Answer (score 0):

Ну если на классах, то я бы лучше тогда решал через `this`, чтобы не городить всякие `this.actions`, как в примере @meine.

```
class Action {
    func(key) {
        key = this['handle' + key];
        if('function' === typeof key) {
            return key();
        }
    }

    handleOne() {
        return "1";
    }

    handleTwo() {
        console.log('2');
    }

    handleThree() {
        console.log('3');
    }

    handleOther() {
        console.log('other');
    }
}
let act = new Action();
console.log(act.func('One'));
act.func('Two');
```